# Infinite series raised to a power being a power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, complex-analysis

After thinking about how

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\right)^{z} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}$$

I wondered about what kind of sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ satisfies

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\right)^{z} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k \tag{1}$$

for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. For instance, any such sequence would satisfy

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k\right) \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k w^k\right) = \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\right)^z \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\right)^w = \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\right)^{z+w} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k (z+w)^k$$

I will use the notation $(a_n)$ to denote $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ and $(a_n)^z$ to denote $(a_n z^n)$. I would like to find a product $(a_n) \cdot (b_n)$ of such sequences which satisfies

$$(a_n)^z \cdot (a_n)^w = (a_n)^{z+w} \tag{2}$$

for all $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$. If we only consider sequences which satisfy $a_n \binom{n}{k} = a_k a_{n-k}$ for all $k$, then a discrete convolution would be such a product since

$$(a_n)^z \cdot (a_n)^w = (c_n)$$

where

$$c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k a_{n-k} z^k w^{n-k} = a_n \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} z^k w^{n-k} = a_n (z+w)^n$$

as required.

Are there any other sequences which satisfy (2) where the product is a discrete convolution? Are there any other products which satisfy (2), for some subset of sequences satisfying (1)? And more importantly, is $(\frac{1}{n!})$ the only sequence satisfying (1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $a_k$ is a sequence of such that such that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ converges.  Write $c = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$.  Assume $c>0$, let $\log c$ be the natural logarithm of $c$.  Then
$$
\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\right)^z = c^z
= \exp(z\log c) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\log c)^k}{k!} z^k
$$
So, in order to get the equation you request, there must be a number $c>0$ such that
$a_k = \frac{(\log c)^k}{k!}$.

Of course the famous example is where $c=e$, and $\log c = 1$, so $(\log c)^k = 1$.

---

I suppose, in case $c > 0$ fails, then we have to inestigate choosing branches of the logarithm.

For example, we could define $(-1)^z = \exp(i \pi z)$ so that
$$
a_k = \frac{i^k \pi^k}{k!} .
$$

Comment: can choose any positive real number $c$ and have $(a_n)$ satisfy (1)?

Comment: If $c$ is any positive real numbers, then $a_k = (\log c)^k/k!$ satisfies $(1)$.

Comment: and it also satisfies (2) with the discrete convolution -- so there are other sequences, thanks

Comment: are we sure that every sequence which satisfies (1) must also satisfy (2)?

Comment: this should be true since any $a_n = \frac{C^n}{n!}$ works, where $C$ is a fixed complex number