# Sequences satisfying an identity involving a discrete convolution

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, complex-numbers, functional-equations, convolution

Let $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty \cdot (b_n)_{n=0}^\infty = (c_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ where $c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}$.

Following on from a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4046227/infinite-series-raised-to-a-power-being-a-power-series/4046239), I am considering sequences $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ of complex numbers which satisfy

$$(a_n z^n)_{n=0}^\infty \cdot (a_n w^n)_{n=0}^\infty = (a_n (z+w)^n)_{n=0}^\infty \tag{1}$$

for all $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$. I know that one family of such sequences is $a_n = \frac{c^n}{n!}$ for some constant $c \in \mathbb{C}$, since

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (a_k z^k) (a_{n-k} w^{n-k}) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{c^k}{k!} z^k \frac{c^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} w^{n-k} = \frac{c^n}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} z^k w^{n-k} = \frac{c^n}{n!} (z+w)^n$$ as required. In fact, it is easy to see that the requirement

$$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k a_{n-k} z^k w^{n-k} = a_n (z+w)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_n \binom{n}{k} z^k w^{n-k}$$

is equivalent to

$$a_n \binom{n}{k} = a_k a_{n-k} \tag{2}$$

for all $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $0 \leq k \leq n$.

Are the sequences given by $a_n = \frac{c^n}{n!}$ the only sequences satisfying (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all such sequences are of the form $c^n/n!$, except for zero sequence $a_n=0$. Letting $k=1$ in $(1)$, you get
$$
a_n=\frac1{n}a_1a_{n-1},
$$
for all $n\ge 1$. You can then prove by induction that this implies
$$
a_n=\frac{a_1^{n}}{n!}\qquad \text{ for all }n\ge 0.
$$
For the base case, use $a_n\binom{n}k=a_ka_{n-k}$ with $n=k=0$ to get $a_0=a_0^2$, so $a_0$ is $0$ or $1$. If $a_0=0$, you get the zero sequence, and if $a_0=1$, the base case $a_0=(a_1)^0/0!$ is proven, and the inductive step is easy.